# Pass object to new form

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to do something like that:

MainForm:

```
Car car = new Car(); //create new object
Form form2 = new Form(car); //Create new form and pass the car that I've created a line before.
form2.Show(); //Show the second Form
```

Form2:

```
public Car(Car car)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //here the car is visible, in private method below, for the button, I can't get to it.
    }

    private void button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        car.maker = "VW" //update the information about the car. I can't make this line to work, variable "car" is unavailable here, how to get to it?
        this.Close(); //close second form
    }
```

How to get to this object in form2 and give it back to MainForm, when I'll add all the info about the car in form2?

Comment: Why do you want to "give it back" to MainForm? If `Car` is a class, you are modifying the very instance that got passed in, so the changed value should be available from MainForm without giving anything back.

Comment: yes you don't need to set back

Comment: Isn't passing elements to/from/in/out forms the most asked, duplicate question ever on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It probably is, I've lost more than hour on this and it was so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in form2

```
public Car MyCar {get; set;}
```

and set this property

```
Car car = new Car(); //create new object
Form form2 = new Form(); 
form2.MyCar=car;
form2.ShowDialog(); 
// get car here again
 Car car2 =form2.MyCar;
```

Comment: Of course it works. :) It's so obvious that I'm ashamed of myself.